# Are the below two c statements same?

Tags: c

1. `if ( i>=8 || i<0)`
2. `if(!((i>=0) && (i<8)))`

Are the above statements same? if not, for what values of `i` they differ.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Intention is to catch any value of i outside range of 0-7, will both do the same task?

Comment: Yes the result will be the same. Depending on the compiler one might get executed faster than the other.

Comment: Okay, You mean to say '1' might be faster than '2'?

Comment: A good optimizing compiler will generate the exact same code for both.

Comment: If ``i`` is ``volatile`` it should not. In the first ``i`` should be read just once if it's greater than 8. In the second it should be read just once if it's negative.

Comment: So given my intention(to catch any value of 'i' outside range 0-7) '1' and '2' both will do the job but '1' is more readable and might be faster? Am i correct?

Comment: IMO, the readable version would be `if ( i<0 || i>7 )`

Comment: @Coder. '2' might be faster in some situations, with some compilers. Imagine a compiler that does not optimize, and that you have a negative value in ``i``. Then in '2' the second expression will not get evaluated which makes it faster than '1'.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same. By the De Morgan's law the negation of disjunction is the conjuction of the negation.

So (not A) or (not B) is the same of not (A and B). If you say that A is i < 8 and B is i >= 0 you have the answer .

Answer (score 0):

In this case they are the same, but the first statement might evaluate only the first part, so in the future make sure you know what you're doing making swaps like this.

Comment: The second statement also ,might evaluate only the first part.

Comment: @GauravSehgal No, logical AND will execute both.

Comment: @Coder Even if first part is false?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Right! You are correct. Sorry my mistake :)